# Are nonprogrammers welcome on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, questions

I am working on my second start-up [Lotaar](http://lotaar.com), and I am what you guys will call "the idea guy" co-founder. But I am responsible for product development and user experience (UX) along side the normal business responsibilities. And I am now learning HTML and CSS so I will be of more help to my technical co-founder.

The type of questions I normally have relate to things like "Are there templates for Admin panels?" "How should you set up automated transactional emails as regards to content and frequency.", and I might have some newbie CSS, JavaScript and HTML questions.

As these are not hard core programming questions, I am wondering if this site will be appropriate for me. From experience, I believe the product guy should work closely with the programmers so I have assumed you guys/girls will have answers to my questions.

Comment: Questions about StackOverflow itself should be posted at meta.stackoverflow.com, not at stackoverflow.com (which is only for programming-related questions).

Comment: Well, the non-programmer dude managed to get a link to his website in on the first sentence.  *And* get some people to take him seriously, without any of them getting rid of the spam link.  Give him a raise.<br/>Can somebody just get rid of that link please before somebody accidentally clicks it?

Answer (score 5):

While questions like this one might not be entirely welcome, as it's not exactly a programming question, I think you'll find a lot of people willing to jump on your other questions. There are a lot of very experienced and clever people that will be able to answer questions on 'the right way to do things', what tools are available, etc. And equally, there are a lot of us that like an opportunity to score points on 'newbie' questions of all kinds.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't matter whether you are a programmer or not: What matters is whether your questions are programming related. Judging from the titles, I'd say the E-Mail one is definitely one. CSS, Javascript and HTML questions are also welcome. (Be sure to use the search first, though - thousands of those have already been answered!)

I'd say go ahead and ask - you sound like somebody able to ask intelligent questions, and if something is deemed not programming related, it will simply get closed, which is not a catastrophe.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably get better answers to your HTML and CSS questions by posting them on the dedicated SE web design site, [Doctype.com](http://doctype.com/questions).

Comment: Point of interest: DocType *isn't* an SE site; it was *inspired* by it.  http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/stack-overflow-and-doctype/ (Translation: Not run by Jeff et al :p)

Answer (score 0):

From the sample questions you give, I wonder if you might want to direct your questions to http://superuser.com instead.